# sql server sql case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is `=1` doing here ?

```
SELECT TOP 3 
       NewsId,
       NewsTitle, 
       NewsContent   
  FROM disc_News  
 WHERE CASE
         WHEN DatePublish IS NOT NULL and DateExpired IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is just making the whole expression evaluate to true or false. Where clauses are supposed to evaluate Boolean expressions, otherwise you would have a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

It is getting you the records where DatePublish AND DateExpired are NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The following `WHERE` clause should be equivalent

```
WHERE DatePublish IS NOT NULL
   AND DateExpired IS NOT NULL
```